# Schedule page caching in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a fast proxy-ish web server on a raspberry pi. I want it to render my ruby code according to a schedule, then serve the static page to the client (iphone / laptop on local network). I know that rails will cache via

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#page-caching

So, one solution could be to use cron on the raspberry pi to schedule the cache update...Is there a better way? Can I force rails to update the cache autonomously at certain times of day??

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `:expires_in` maybe you can set an amount of time as a period. see more ate: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#configuration

Comment: It seems to me that would just invalidate the cache but not refresh it until the next request...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423511/rails-3-2-pre-render-bake-a-new-page-cache-immediately-after-expiry?rq=1 is close and may be the best we can do

Comment: Have you tried something like cache.write(key, value, :expires_in => 1.minute) ? not really sure but I think it may work.